# TextView null in Master Detail Flow template

Tags: android, listview, textview, master-detail

I am using the Master Detail Flow template in android. I want to access the items in the list programmatically when the app starts in order to set the font size and the color of the TextViews that are there. If I code inside onResume (either ItemListActivity or ItemListFragment), the ListView is not null but the 3 TextViews (children of the ListView) are null.

```
public void updateActivity( )
{
 ViewGroup leftPane = ( ViewGroup ) findViewById( R.id.item_list );
 FrameLayout frameLayout = ( FrameLayout ) leftPane.getChildAt( 0 );
 FrameLayout frameLayout2 = ( FrameLayout ) frameLayout.getChildAt( 1 );
 ListView listView = ( ListView ) frameLayout2.getChildAt( 1 );  // listView NOT null
 TextView item0 = ( TextView ) listView.getChildAt( 0 ); // item0 is NULL !!!!!
}
```

I came up with this code inside ItemListActivity as a (dirty) fix, and I am not sure it would work all the time and would be device independent:

```
public View onCreateView( String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) 
{
 // started is an int instance variable, initialized at 0
 Log.w( "MA", "Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  " + started ); 
 // if started <= 40 ==> item0 is NULL inside updateActivity 
 if( started == 41) // ==> item0 NOT null inside updateActivity 
   updateActivity( );
 started++;
 return super.onCreateView( name, context, attrs );
}
```

That works but I am looking for a (much) better solution; here is the output in LogCat (it does stop at 48):

There seems to be some interleaved execution of the various life cycle methods involved. There must be a way to code inside a method that guarantees that all the Views have been instantiated before that method executes; I have tried to override a lot of methods from the Activity, FragmentActivity, ListFragment and Fragment classes; no luck so far, the TextViews (children of the ListView) are NULL inside all of those methods. By the way, the other TextViews are still NULL when started is equal to 41, the second one becomes NOT null when started equals 43 and the third one becomes NOT null when started equals 45.
Any idea? Thank you for any help.

```
......
05-16 19:27:36.460: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  37
05-16 19:27:36.460: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  38
05-16 19:27:36.460: W/MA(3155): Inside ItemListActivity:onResume
05-16 19:27:36.460: W/MA(3155): Inside ItemListFragment:onResume
05-16 19:27:36.484: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  39
05-16 19:27:36.484: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  40
05-16 19:27:36.632: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  41
05-16 19:27:36.632: W/MA(3155): Inside checkActivity
05-16 19:27:36.632: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  42
05-16 19:27:36.640: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  43
05-16 19:27:36.640: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  44
05-16 19:27:36.648: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  45
05-16 19:27:36.656: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  46
05-16 19:27:36.742: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  47
05-16 19:27:36.742: W/MA(3155): Inside Activity:onCreateView, started =  48
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you have to implement custom adapter. From `onCreate` of your activity create an object of `CustomAdapter` and pass `list of data` in the `constructor`.

inside `CustomAdapter` you have to override `getView()` in that inflate layout for each row(Here yo)u have to call `findViewById(id)` for `textView()`) and based on your data `setFont()` and `setColor()` of `textView`.

Comment: I have not tried your proposed answer but I would be surprised if it worked: these TextViews do not have an id so I do not think I can use findViewById to access them.

Comment: The TextViews are not listed in the xml layout (so they cannot be given an id there); the number of TextViews is dynamic, I do not want to hard code them in the xml layout.

Comment: in that case you can call txtView.setId(uniqueId); in your java code.

Comment: The TextView is null (see my original post) if I try to access it inside onResume. Calling setId with it assumes that it is not null.

Comment: You must be having some adapter to populate your list and in that you were setting some layout which will be having textViews. If you are using listActivity then default id for textView inside a list is android.R.id.text1(for main text) and android.R.id.text2(for subtext of each row).